# I need to create a redirect URI for my app, and use it in authenticating quizlet access. How do I do it?

Tags: redirect, oauth, uri

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
I tried using different web adress, including some of my own, but it all fails. I don't really understand how to get a proper URI. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect_uri is used for your APP to verify the response(such as token) from server,
You can set your redirect_uri when you created you APP,
It can be any URL, even www.baidu.com or www.google.com ,
but NOTE:**The URL you used in your APP,MUST match the one you set when you created your new APP.**